# Any ideas on how to convert this date column into a common format? The document date should start from 2019_10_04

Tags: python, date

I'm trying to convert the date of this dataframe column to a common format, but I can't figure out how to do that. The document date should start from 2019_10_04. I don't understand what the relationship is between the formats. I tried using infer_datetime_format=True and couldn't fix it:
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBEkj.png)

Answer (score 1):

Don't post pictures of the dataframe, give the actual sample data, like I'm doing below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1570147200299, 8224.43, 0.167953],
                   [1570147200370, 8224.80, 0.152024]],
                  columns=['date','price','amount'])
```

So that column is in epoch unix timestamp, which is the number of seconds (or in this case looks like milliseconds) that have elapsed since January 1, 1970. Just need to convert.  Here is a *pandas* reference for timestamps, which shows epoch ones.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html

```
df['date_convert'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='ms').dt.normalize()
```

**Ouput:**

```
print(df)
            date    price    amount date_convert
0  1570147200299  8224.43  0.167953   2019-10-04
1  1570147200370  8224.80  0.152024   2019-10-04
```